# Gradle war does not include bpmn diagram folder

Tags: java, gradle, bpmn

My project contains bpmn diagrams in folder : src/main/java/com/company/core/bpm/diagram

While taking war from commend prompt with commend `gradle war` or `gradle build` the war file is not included in the war.
But taking the war using eclipse it include the diagram folder.

It considers the diagram folder as empty folder and not including i think, is there any way to include the diagram folder in war when build from commend prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources, that is files that aren't `.java` files should go in the `resources` subfolder and gradle will pick them up from there. See the see [section 23.4 of the Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N12116)

If for some reason you need your resources somewhere else, you can change the project layout to fit what you need. For example

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
             srcDir 'src/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

But if you make you java source directory and the resource directory the same, I'd expect all you source files to end up in the war as well. So better to keep them separated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after placing the diagrams in resource folder it works